# SAS PROC SQL - How to compute date difference

Tags: sas

I'm using SAS with SQL procedures.
I need to compute a field as a date difference from today, ex the number of days from the birth date.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE myTable AS
SELECT BIRTH_DATE, <some function> AS DAYS_BETWEEN_BIRTHDATE_AND_TODAY
FROM someTable
```

What's the best way to do this and what if I want to compute monthly difference or yearly difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`INTCK()`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm)** to get the number of days between `today()` and `Birth_Date` column.

**Code**

```
proc sql;
  create table myTable as
  select Birth_Date, intck('day', Birth_date, today()) as No_of_days
  from someTable;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this function, I'm looking for other solutions.

```
%let today=%sysfunc(date());
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE myTable AS
SELECT BIRTH_DATE, 
intck('DAYS', datepart(BIRTH_DATE), &today) AS DAYS_BETWEEN_BIRTHDATE_AND_TODAY
FROM someTable
```

Is possible to change 'DAYS' with  'MONTHS' or 'YEARS

Comment: Yes, if you look at the link that Wanderer posted you can see the various intervals you can use.